# Windows MySQL: Create table with DATA DIRECTORY

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm using Mysql on Windows 10, can I create a new table on another drive(different than the drive that contains the MySQL data directory) without creating a new MySQL instance?

When trying to create the new table with "Data Directory" option I noticed that it says on the GUI that "Data Directory" option only works for MyISAM engine and not working on Windows. My table used InnoDB. And it really doesn't works after my try.

Can this ever be done on Windows 10, if so ,which version is required?

Comment: [MySQL 5.6 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  Creating a Tablespace Outside of the Data Directory](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tablespace-placing.html)